# What is the difference between the two JavaScript expressions?

Tags: javascript

I am using filter method of JavaScript to remove the duplicate entries and I am using the below syntax:

```
var dataArray = ['g','o','o','g','l','e']
dataArray.filter((value, index) => dataArray.indexOf(value) === index)
```

The above code works fine and returns me an array by removing the duplicate values. But, when I add a **{** curly braces after arrow function it returns an empty array.

```
var dataArray = ['g','o','o','g','l','e']
dataArray.filter((value, index) => { dataArray.indexOf(value) === index })
```

I am unable to figure out what's the actual difference between both of the syntaxes and why the second one is returning me an empty array.

Comment: The first is an expression, the second a block. `{ }` are not only for cosmetics.

Comment: you need a return statement with curly brackets.

Comment: try to log the result of calling `dataArray.filter(...)` to know the difference. 2nd code example will not work like you expect it to.

Comment: You can try reading up the comparison in the mdn documentation:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the return keyword if use curly brace:

```js
var dataArray = ['g','o','o','g','l','e']
dataArray = dataArray.filter((value, index) => { return dataArray.indexOf(value) === index });

console.log(dataArray);
```

Though, I prefer using *Set* to remove duplicate items from array:

```js
var dataArray = ['g','o','o','g','l','e']
dataArray = [...new Set(dataArray)];

console.log(dataArray);
```

Comment: As it is shown in the duplicate...